# NIntegration Monte-Carlo N-dim Hypercube

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to integrate a simple monotonally decreasing (finite, no oscillations) function over the hypercube [0,1]^D so its basically D (around 30) integrals. The integrand decreases very fast though so the biggest contribution comes from the area around the origin (e.g. [0,0.1]^D).

I get the error:

```
NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 47094 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 1.363238702270981`*^146 and 1.4128586288456764`*^144 for the integral and error estimates.
```

I used the method QuasiMonteCarlo. Can I add some sampling points around the origin to make it more precise?

Comment: This is an empty and meaningless  talk without your code.

Comment: Can't you break up your region into two or more pieces and integrate the pieces separately

Comment: What do you mean by "finite"? Is the integrand bounded on the closed hypercube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I add some sampling points around the origin to make it more precise?

What (I think) you want to do can be achieved by partitioning the ranges of the integration region.

Here as an example:

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]

Plot3D[1/(1 + x^2 + y^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]

NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
 NIntegrate[
       1/(1 + x^2 + y^2), 
       {x, -10, -1, -0.1, 0.1, 1, 10}, 
       {y, -10, -1, -0.1, 0.1, 1, 10}, 
        Method -> "MonteCarlo", PrecisionGoal -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I wanted! Takes more time now but duh

Comment: @VincentN23 Great, good luck!